# C++ priority queue class using heap class

Tags: c++

So I need to create a priority queue class with functions Add(), Top(), and Pop() and member variable Heap. In general, how would I use the heap class (below) to make the above functions? I am creating an array of 100 ints ranging from 1-100.

```
    #pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Heap
{
private:
    bool minHeap;
    int size;
    int end;
    int* arr;

public:
    Heap(bool minHeap = true)
    {
        this->minHeap = minHeap;
        end = 0;
        size = 50;
        arr = new int[size];
    }
    void Resize(int newSize)
    {
        int* temp = new int[newSize];
        delete[] arr;
        arr = temp;
        size = newSize;
    }
    void HeapSort(vector<int> &vec)
    {
        Resize(vec.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        {
            arr[i] = vec[i];
            end++;
        }
        BuildHeap();

        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        {
            vec[i] = arr[0];
            int temp = arr[0];
            arr[0] = arr[--end];
            arr[end] = temp;
            Heapify(0);
        }
    }
    void Heapify(int index)
    {
        int leftChild = LeftChild(index);
        int rightChild = RightChild(index);
        int target = -1;

        if (minHeap)
        {
            if (leftChild < end && arr[index] > arr[leftChild])
                target = leftChild;
            else
                target = index;

            if (rightChild < end && arr[target] > arr[rightChild])
                target = rightChild;
        }
        else//Max Heap
        {
            if (leftChild < end && arr[index] < arr[leftChild])
                target = leftChild;
            else
                target = index;

            if (rightChild < end && arr[target] < arr[rightChild])
                target = rightChild;
        }

        if (target != index)
        {
            int temp = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[target];
            arr[target] = temp;
            Heapify(target);
        }
    }
    void BuildHeap()
    {
        for (int i = (end - 1) / 2; i >= 0; i--)
            Heapify(i);
    }
    void PrintHeap()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < end && i < 50; i++)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    void Add(int val)
    {
        if (end == size)
            Grow();
        arr[end++] = val;
    }
    void Grow()
    {
        size *= 2;
        int* temp = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
            temp[i] = arr[i];

        delete[] arr;
        arr = temp;
    }
    ~Heap()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }
    int Parent(int index)
    {
        return (index - 1) / 2;
    }
    int LeftChild(int index)
    {
        return 2 * index + 1;
    }
    int RightChild(int index)
    {
        return 2 * index + 2;
    }

};
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and not really a whole lot of effort to try and solve the problem. Take a stab at it.

Comment: It seems surprising that you allow a `std::vector` parameter to one function, yet manage memory locally in a plain array. You should use a `std::vector` in your own class.

Comment: My biggest problem right now is properly creating a heap member variable within the priority queue class  and using the variable to get the output for each of the functions, Add, Top, and Pop. The Heap member variable needs to be able to take the bool min/max which is input through the priority queue class constructor.